# javascript banner not appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i cant figure out why, it was there i clicked and now it wont show, anyone able to help - i followed a tutorial to make this and copied it over from my other site with adjusted dimensions, perhaps i have missed something - the only thing that has changed is the dimensions of the images, i have adjusted the image links...

HTML :

```
<body>

<div class="header">

<div class="headercontent">

<img src="Images/logoandbuttons.png"/>

<!--BANNER CODE-->

<div id="banner">


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript">  </script>


<img src="Images/banner1.jpg" class="active" />
<img src="images/banner4.jpg" />
<img src="images/banner2.jpg" />
<img src="images/banner3.jpg" />

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
setInterval(function () {
    //Get current active image
    var active = $('#banner .active');

    // If there is another image(object) left then make that image next
    // If not, go back to the first image of the banner div
    if (active.next().length > 0) var next = active.next();
    else var next = $('#banner img:first');

    //Get the next image ready by modifying the z-index
    next.css('z-index', '2');

    //Fade out the active image, then
    active.fadeOut(1000, function () {
    //Move the active image to the back of the pile, show it and             remove         the active class
    active.css('z-index', '1').show().removeClass('active');
    //Make the next image the active one  
    next.css('z-index', '3').addClass('active');
    });


}, 3000);
});

</script>

<!--END OF BANNER CODE-->

</div>

</div>


</body>


</html>
```

CSS :

```
    * {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

.header {
height: 150px;
width: 1920px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
background-color:#000

}

.headercontent {
height: 150px;
width: 950px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;  

}

#banner {
position: absolute;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
height: 130px;
width: 670px;
margin-top: 10px;
top: -150px;
left: 85px;
}

#banner img {

position:absolute;
z-index:1;
}

#banner img.active {

z-index:3;  
}
```

Comment: I'd post this in JSFiddle.net so that it's easier for us to see what's wrong. Have you opened the developer tools of your browser? Ah, note that you sometimes refer to "Images" and sometimes "images", depending on where this is hosted, that might not work.

Comment: it wont be of much use from what i have put in, i have run jshint and found the following ; 1 - unrecoverable syntax error at the end of the javascript. 2 next already defined and next used out of scope in the javascript (which was copied from a working version so unsure)

Comment: Are you storing your image files in Images/ or images/? It's inconsistent.

Comment: i've used src=" to locate the images so surely thats irrelevant?

Comment: The #banner css places the div outside of the screen? try removing the top and left props. The JS is correct because I got it to work using colored divs instead of imgs: http://jsfiddle.net/5rj8C/3/

Comment: sorted! was the #banner css thanks!